# Setting default LAF's JTextField dimensions

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, look-and-feel, uidefaults

Is it possible to override the LAF's default dimensions of a JTextField with UIDefaults?

Comment: please see [UIManagerDefaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) by @camickr

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the padding, or the insets, but certainly not the raw dimension.   That dimension accounts for things like the number of characters the field is supposed to show, and the font.

Comment: +1 not, isn't there, there isn't conflict :-), betweens keys in UIManager and LayoutManager, and/or predefinned methods in JTextField API